# change the icon in expandable view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table that has an expandable view. on a click of a plus sign it expands, but i wish to change the plus sign to minus (`fa fa-plus to fa fa-minus`)when the view is in expanded form and back to plus when it is in compressed form, can anyone please tell how to do so (code @[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/aeab478c/1/))

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#report tbody tr:odd td:first-child").click(function(){
            $this=$(this);
            $this.parent().next("tr").toggle();
            $this.find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
        });
    });
        </script>

       <table id="report" border="1" style="width:100%" >
        <tr>
            <th> First </th>
            <th> Second </th>
            <th> Third </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
             <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10">
                dummy text 1<br>
                dummy text 1<br>
                dummy text 1<br>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
```

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/aeab478c/3/

Comment: If this works for you then let me know so i can post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple way then use both icons with property `display:none` and `display:block` with common class and just toggle them.

See in [action](http://jsfiddle.net/aeab478c/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Apply some class to parent to identify when you have expanded element. For expanded element hide plus icon and show minus icon and vice-versa.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggler').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.toggler {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
}
.icon-minus {
  display: none;
}
.active .icon-plus {
  display: none;
}
.active .icon-minus {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggler">
  <span class="icon icon-plus">+</span>
  <span class="icon icon-minus">-</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation, I did not find any `element` with class `arrow` but I assume that you need to toggle between `fa-plus` and `fa-minus` on `collapse` and `expand`. So you can achieve it as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#report tbody tr:odd td:first-child").click(function(){
         $this=$(this);
         $this.parent().next("tr").toggle();
         $this.find("i").toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
         //you find the "i" element in td and toggle its fa-plus and fa-minus
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/aeab478c/4/)**